# Pandas.to_datetime() A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have not received this copy warning with other functions and I have not found a way to address it.

Here is my code:

```
div_df.loc[:,"Ann.Date"] = pd.to_datetime(div_df.loc[:,"Ann.Date"], format='%d %b %Y')

/volume1/homes/id/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1843: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
```

I have not found a solution anywhere other than the following:

```
div_df.loc[:,"Ann.Date"] = pd.to_datetime(div_df.loc[:,"Ann.Date"], format='%d %b %Y', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Simply use `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d %b %Y')`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I tried it and it is the same warning. <ipython-input-219-3e2d842d6d9e>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  div_df["Ann.Date"] = pd.to_datetime(div_df["Ann.Date"], format='%d %b %Y')

Comment: Using .loc() is generally a solution to cater for the SettingWithCopyWarning  If it still got the warning, can't imagine why removing the .loc could solve it.  In your case, probably your div_df is itself a copy of slice from some other dataframe.  You may need to try making a copy of it by e.g.  div_df = another_df[some_selection_mask].copy()

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/15070697).  The last sentence:  `The solution here is to either make a copy() of df, or use loc, as before.`

Comment: @seabean thank you. I used div_df = another_df.copy(deep=True) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: That's good you solved it. The default of .copy() is already with `deep=True`, so I didn't tell you to add this parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the discussion in comments, the root cause is probably your dataframe `div_df` is built from a slice of another dataframe.  Most commonly, we either solve this kind of SettingWithCopyWarning problem by using `.loc` or using [`.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Now, you have already used `.loc` and still get the problem. So, suggest to use [`.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) when you created the dataframe `div_df`, with syntax, like:

```
div_df = another_df[some_selection_mask].copy()
```

Here, probably you have specified some filtering condition on the base df so that the final df created is a slice of that base df. Or, the base df is already a slice of another df.  You can use `.copy()` without specifying `deep=True` since it is the default.  You can refer to [this webpage](https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/#understanding-views-and-copies-in-pandas) for more information on it.

> The parameter deep determines if you want a view (deep=False) or copy
> (deep=True). deep is True by default, so you can omit it to get a copy

The SO page I mentioned in comment, i.e. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15070697) offers very good info.  The webpage I included above has a very comprehensive information and solutions for this topic.

Comment: I have been looking for this comment long time! I had the same issue because I did something like df2=df1.query('xxxxxxx') before the datetime transform. I changed it to df2=df1.query('xxxxxxx').copy() and it no longer complains.